# How to skip the installation of sub-setup when main app is run?

Tags: inno-setup

I need to run the another application(patch for another main application1) along with the application2. If the application1 is not installed, i need to skip the installation of patch setup for application1 when application 2 is running.

Previously i just checked by installing the application2 in application1 installed machine. It works fine.

If i run the application2 in aaplication1 not installed machine, application2 rollback occur.

Could anyone please provide me your suggestion to skip the installation of appplication1 patch setup while application2 is run in application1 not installed machine?

Kindly directly me to some possible useful link if exists.

Note: skipping the installation of appplication1 patch setup will not affect the application2 running. Application2 will fine without any interrrupting.

Comment: Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: It's not 100% clear to me what is conditional on what. Maybe if you showed us some of the existing code and what it's not doing we can advise further.